# reading from an array and creating an workbook that is .xls in 2003 format through POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am working as java developer and i want to convert an .csv file to .xls 2003 format so that my csv will be converted into .xls file the structure of my .csv file would be like

```
REC_STATUS,TRADE_ID,SETTLEMENT_DATE,TRADE_EFFECTIVE_DATE,PAYMENT_TYPE,VERSION,BREAK_DOWN_BUCKET,CAUSE,NUM_CASHFLOWS_AFFECTED,PROFILE
Found only in File :B,178942690,01-Feb-16,03-Dec-14,"Coupon",5,NOISY_BREAK_BUCKET,REC_TOOL_ISSUE_PAYMENT_DIRECTION_MISMATCH | REC_TOOL_ISSUE_NOTIONAL_MISMATCH | TRADE_VERSION,1,AVS Offshore
Found only in File :B,197728700,Various,21-Dec-15,"Coupon,(x20)",2,ACTUAL DATA BREAK BUCKET,ACTUAL_DATA_BREAK,20,AVS Offshore
```

now i have used the open csv parser `(http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)` for this and coded as shown below

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
                new FileReader("c:/xxx.csv"), ',', '"');
 // Read all rows at once
 List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();
```

now please advise after reading i want to create an .xls workbook in similar fashion as .csv was created above so i have to read the values first i have to read the header and then corresponding values and have to write them in .xls 2003 format please advise how i would achieve this I am using POI 3.10 version for it

Folks please advise how to put array contents in workbook now

```
enter code here
```

Comment: You can directly open csv files with excel and save in xls format. Not a programmatic solution though.

Comment: :) @SendhilkumarAlalasundaram

Comment: I have done some manipulation in open csv code so that manipulation is done and things are in array now so please advise how to put array contents in workbook now

Answer (score 0):

```
class Handle
{
 public static void data(List list,String path)
 {       
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("Sheet");
    int i=0;
    while(i<list.size())
    {
       HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
       String [] data =  (String[]) list.get(i);
       int j=0;
       while(j<data.length)
       {
           HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(j);
           cell.setCellValue(data[j]);
           j++;
       }
       i++;
     }
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path+".xls");
     wb.write(fos);
     fos.flush();
     fos.close();
     wb.close();                        
   }
}
```

As told by @gagravarr you can use common SS classes to handle both ''.xls'' and ''.xlsx'' format with the same code..

Comment: No you don't - you can't use the common SS classes to handle both transparently. See the [converting guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html) to update your old HSSF code

Comment: Didnt get you @Gagravarr .. What do you want to convey??

Comment: You state that they have to use HSSF for xls and XSSF for xlsx, this is incorrect. They can use the common SS classes and handle both with the same code

Comment: That code won't work - have a read of the documentation I linked to and/or try it!

Comment: Nope, it won't. Try compiling it and you'll see!